# Random edge or object appearing on my sculpt

Tags: sculpting

I did a bool operation to seperate a par of my mesh after then booled them both with a uv sphear!while sculpting i noticed this unnecessary edge which gets engraved in mesh whin i apply clay brush on it if i smooth it then it appears again! How to get rid of it?[image: right side near the cursour its impossible to find in edit mode]

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: there must be bad topology on this area, go in Edit mode and make sur you have no floating edge, or hole in your mesh, etc...